# messages bundle with dynamic key in struts2

Tags: struts2, ognl

I have a problem with displaying a message from messages bundle with key passed as a tag argument. Since version 2.3, struts tags don't allow runtime expressions.

I have a custom tag with `fieldName` parameter and I want to retrieve a message with use of this parameter, like in previous versions of the framework: `<s:text name="${fieldName}"/>`

Neither `<s:text>` nor `<s:property>` work for me.

I tried every solution found in web, but nothing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use OGNL or use `<s:set>` tag

```
<s:set name="fname">
  ${fieldName}
</s:set>

<s:text name="%{#fname}"/>
```

Comment: @joval: What I meant is maybe you can use your `fieldName` variable directly in `<s:text>` tag w/o `<s:set>` -> `<s:text name="%{fieldName}"/>`.

Comment: I have tried that in the first instance, but this doesn't work.